# Pandas : Use groupby on each element of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Maybe I'm missing the obvious.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this :

```
   id        product              categories
    0        Silmarillion         ['Book', 'Fantasy']
    1        Headphones           ['Electronic', 'Material']
    2        Dune                 ['Book', 'Sci-Fi']
```

I'd like to use the groupby function to count the number of appearances of each element in the categories column, so here the result would be

```
Book       2
Fantasy    1
Electronic 1
Material   1
Sci-Fi     1
```

However when I try using a groupby function, pandas counts the occurrences of the entire list instead of separating its elements. I have tried multiple different ways of handling this, using tuples or splits, but this far I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: Aside: pandas doesn't fully support non-scalar entries at this point, and you can sometimes get mysterious failures when using them.  It's usually safer to rework your frame so that each row contains only scalar entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can normalize the records by stacking them then call `value_counts()`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['categories'].tolist()).stack().value_counts()
Out: 
Book          2
Fantasy       1
Material      1
Sci-Fi        1
Electronic    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also call `pd.value_counts` directly on a list.
You can generate the appropriate list via `numpy.concatenate`, `itertools.chain`, or `cytoolz.concat`

```
from cytoolz import concat
from itertools import chain
```

***`cytoolz.concat`***

```
pd.value_counts(list(concat(df.categories.values.tolist())))
```

***`itertools.chain`***

```
pd.value_counts(list(chain(*df.categories.values.tolist())))
```

***`numpy.unique` + `numpy.concatenate`***

```
u, c = np.unique(np.concatenate(df.categories.values), return_counts=True)
pd.Series(c, u)
```

---

All yield

```
Book          2
Electronic    1
Fantasy       1
Material      1
Sci-Fi        1
dtype: int64
```

---

***time testing***

[image]

Comment: Thank you @NickilMaveli... I missed that ;-)

Comment: I get that confusion arising ;-)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
In [58]: df['categories'].apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()
Out[58]:
Book          2
Fantasy       1
Electronic    1
Sci-Fi        1
Material      1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @ayhan, why did you remove your solution? I guess it was better than mine

Comment: @MaxU `.apply(pd.Series)` seemed more explicit than `pd.DataFrame(ser.tolist())`. Mine looks like a side-effect which may not work in the future.

Comment: @ayhan, but `pd.DataFrame(df['categories'].tolist())` will most probably be faster compared to `df['categories'].apply(pd.Series)`. Anyway for the sake of completeness (and having a choice) i would ask you to undelete your answer ;-)

Comment: I've just tried both. They both work but the "tolist()" variant seems to be much faster

Comment: @Skum, yes, i also like ayhan's solution more than mine! :-)