# Pandas - groupby where each row has multiple values stored in list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with last.fm listening data and have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
           Artist Plays                                   Genres
0   John Coltrane    10             [jazz, modal jazz, hard bop]
1     Miles Davis    15  [jazz, cool jazz, modal jazz, hard bop]
2  Charlie Parker    20                            [jazz, bebop]
```

I want to group the data by the genres and then aggregate by the sum of plays for each genre, to get something like this:

```
        Genre Plays
0        jazz    45
1  modal jazz    25
2    hard bop    25
3       bebop    20
4   cool jazz    15
```

Been trying to figure this out for a while now but can't seem to find the solution. Do I need to change the way that the genre data is stored?

I was able to find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780225/pandas-use-groupby-on-each-element-of-list) which addresses a similar question, but that user was only looking to get the count of each list value. This gets me about halfway there, but I couldn't figure out how to use that to aggregate another column in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not store lists in a `DataFrame`, so yes, probably best to change how they are stored. With this you can use some `join` + `str.get_dummies` + `.multiply`. Choose a `sep` that doesn't appear in any of your strings.

```
sep = '*'
df.Genres.apply(sep.join).str.get_dummies(sep=sep).multiply(df.Plays, axis=0).sum()
```

#### Output

```
bebop         20
cool jazz     15
hard bop      25
jazz          45
modal jazz    25
dtype: int64
```

---

An easier form to work with would be if your lists were split across lines as in:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.Genres.values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame('Genres'),
                 df[['Plays', 'Artist']]], axis=1)

       Genres  Plays          Artist
0        jazz     10   John Coltrane
0  modal jazz     10   John Coltrane
0    hard bop     10   John Coltrane
1        jazz     15     Miles Davis
1   cool jazz     15     Miles Davis
1  modal jazz     15     Miles Davis
1    hard bop     15     Miles Davis
2        jazz     20  Charlie Parker
2       bebop     20  Charlie Parker
```

Making it a simple sum within genres:

```
df1.groupby('Genres').Plays.sum()

Genres
bebop         20
cool jazz     15
hard bop      25
jazz          45
modal jazz    25
Name: Plays, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Interesting solution. Never seen the get_dummies method before. Thanks for the suggestion about structuring the genres, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @bill it's not bad for small datasets. But the combination of `Series.apply` + `Series.str` makes it two very slow operations. For larger datasets, it's likely much faster to use the second method and recreate an entirely new `DataFrame`